# PySide6 сохраняем cookie

Tags: python, cookie, pyside6

Есть программы, там две вкладки (сайт один и тот же)
Как сделать так, что для каждой вкладки сохранялись cookie в разные папки? возможно это сделать ?
В пример возьмем вк, в одной вкладке один пользователь, в другой вкладке другой пользователь.
При перезапуске программы сохранялись данные.
как это можно реализовать?
Код прилагаю.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget)


class MyWebView(QWebEngineView):
    def createWindow(self, type_):
        if type_ == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserBackgroundTab:
            # Вызывается при Ctrl+ЛКМ / СКМ
            return self.window().add_tab(self.url())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Программа')
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        web_view = MyWebView()
        web_view.setUrl('https://vk.com/')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view, 'dex')

        web_view2 = MyWebView()
        web_view2.setUrl('https://vk.com/')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view2, 'Romir')

    def add_tab2(self, url):
        web_view2 = MyWebView()
        web_view2.setUrl(url)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view2, 'user1')
        return web_view2  # Возвращаем QWebEngineView для запроса

    def add_tab(self, url):
        web_view = MyWebView()
        web_view.setUrl(url)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view, 'user2')
        return web_view  # Возвращаем QWebEngineView для запроса


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    availableGeometry = mainWin.screen().availableGeometry()
    mainWin.resize(availableGeometry.width() * 3 / 3, availableGeometry.height() * 3 / 3)
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies храняться в профиле пользователя, поэтому нужно указать profile для `QWebEnginePage`.
По умолчанию `QWebEnginePage` работает с профилем `default`. Но можно создать свой собственный `QWebEngineProfile` для каждой из страниц - тогда cookies будут сохраняться отдельно в каждом из них.